# What is the purpose of the "system" folder in rails "public/system/"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

The standard place to store non-precompiled public assets in a rails app is in "public/system." Is there any reason for this? I'd like to keep things simple, why shouldn't I just put assets in the "public" folder?

Comment: Matter of general preference, you can name your sub folders off of public/ anything you like and they will still be included.  It also provides some level of organization instead of putting umpteen files in a top level folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `public/system` folder isn't a Rails standard per se or even a documented recommendation. Deployment tools like Capistrano adopted that convention as a suggestion for you to organize user assets that are shared between deployments and shouldn't be in your repository. The idea is symlink `public/system` to capistrano's `shared/system`, which is outside of the releases folder.

If you take a look at [paperclip's](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)(which is a widely used upload library) docs you'll find:

> By default, this location is
>   :rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename. This location was chosen because, on standard Capistrano deployments,
>   the public/system directory can be symlinked to the app's shared
>   directory, meaning it survives between deployments.

In your development environment you're supposed to ignore that folder in `.gitignore` if you're willing to adopt that convention.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, the app uses Paperclip and Capistrano.